# Message from Syslogd

Tags: linux, crash, syslogd

During a ssh session running a long rsync-job the system crashed and I received the following output in my shell:

```
Message from syslogd@x123 at Aug 21 13:42:05 ...
 kernel:[1050642.629179] ------------[ cut here ]------------

Message from syslogd@x123 at Aug 21 13:42:05 ...
 kernel:[1050642.629670] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP

Message from syslogd@x123 at Aug 21 13:42:05 ...
 kernel:[1050642.629950] last sysfs file: /sys/devices/virtual/block/md0/md/mismatch_cnt

Message from syslogd@x123 at Aug 21 13:42:05 ...
 kernel:[1050642.636405] Stack:

Message from syslogd@x123 at Aug 21 13:42:05 ...
 kernel:[1050642.638071] Call Trace:

Message from syslogd@x123 at Aug 21 13:42:05 ...
 kernel:[1050642.640982] Code: 2e 48 8b 43 30 48 8b 53 28 48 8d 4b 28 48 89 42 08 48 89 10 49 8b 06 48 89 48 08 48 89 43 28 4c 89 73 30 49 89 0e e9 c6 00 00 00 <0f> 0b eb fe 49 8b 44 24 d8 48 b9 00 00 00 00 00 16 00 00 4c 8b
```

Since that occurrence I can't connect to my Debian Server. Even after reboots. However I can connect via ssh in Rescue Mode but I don't know what to do in order to get the system back to normal operation mode.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like your server is using software RAID and it's now suffering somehow. Do you still see all your disk mounts in rescue mode?

Comment: Hello Janne,
yes I am using a software Raid. When I do ls /dev, I see sda, sda1, sda2, sdb, sdb1 and sdb2.
But when I check ls /mnt, I only see cdrom/  dvd/  external/  external1/  floppy/  sda2/  sdb1/  sdb2/  test/

Does that mean that one hard disk is broken?

Comment: Do you have all the data accessible you should have? :) Does the "mount" command return all the same mount points that you have defined in /etc/fstab?

Comment: I fixed the problem with e2fsck. There seemed to be a problem with blocks.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem with e2fsck on my RAID-1 system. There seemed to be a problem with files and blocks.
Solution is as follows:

Log in in Rescue Mode and execute the following:

```
# umount -a

# e2fsck -f -y /dev/sda2

# e2fsck -f -y /dev/sdb2

# shutdown -r -n now
```

Comment: Fixing individual disks within a software RAID sounds scary to me. Wouldn't it be better to run e2fsck against the software RAID device (/dev/md0)?

Comment: Well, I guess you are right. However, In my case it worked just fine.

Comment: RAID-1, I presume? Then it might work.

Comment: exactly, RAID-1 it is.

Comment: fsck on individual drives and the RAID stack are different.  Do individual first, then the stack.  For not a RAID doing touch ./forcefsck and rebooting is much simpler, it will fsck the root before it mounts it.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following command to get a list of processes running `syslog`:

```
ps -ef |grep syslog
```

Which will in turn print out something like so:

```
root      3947     1 13 Aug14 ?        00:58:05 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
root     28092 25977  0 05:36 pts/0    00:00:00 grep syslog
```

Identify the process you want to terminate (in this case the one with id 3947) and kill it like so:

```
kill -9 3947
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Can you please provide a little more detail as to how this should be run and what exactly it does?

Comment: I've edited your answer to give it more clarity, but you really need to explain why syslog is the culprit, and how to identify it.